# Github Flow removing commit and changes in history

Tags: git, github

I'm looking to use GitHub flow, I have a question.

My Repo (A, B, C, D are merge commits from merging in a Pull Request)

(master) -------------A------B-------C-------D(HEAD)

say what I committed in B has a defect, but I need to do a deployment containing C and D. How can I remove/stash B until after the deployment and put it back in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `git revert B -m 1` you create a new commit that undoes the changes that you introduced by merging in the PR branch. You can then later do the same again, but with the revert commit in the command to revert the revert. There you don't need the `-m 1` parameter as it is no merge commit that you revert.

Comment: Does reverting B in this way keep the changes pushed in C & D? What is something was changed in B, then subsequently changed in C or D?

Comment: Reverting just creates an additional commit that undoes what was done in the commit you revert. You will still have the merge in the history and C and D are not touched. If you changed the same code in C or D, you will get a conflict that you need to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.  I would suggest that a revert is the best option.  People tend to dislike the resulting history, but IMO they're putting an aesthetic sense ahead of practical concerns.  So you have

```
A -- B -- C -- D <--(master)
```

If you do

```
git revert B
```

you'll get

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- ~B <--(master)
```

which produces the same tree as

```
A -- C -- D <--(master)
```

You should test that as it is a new state of the tree.

Then to fix B you'd recreate its changes

```
git revert ~B
```

giving

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- ~B -- ~~B <--(master)
```

(where `~~B` makes the same changes as `B`) and then do your fixes.  I would apply the changes using `--amend` so that you finish with

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- ~B -- B+ <--(master)
```

(where `B+` applies the corrected changes from `B`).

Now some people don't like seeing the `B` changes done, then undone, then redone.  I think this is a bit of hubris (and not the useful kind), but hey, if you really want, there are options as I say.

You can choose to rebase instead.  Since this is clearly changes that have been pushed, you'll need to coordinate all of the developers as they'll have to perform the steps outlined in "recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

```
git rebase --interactive A master
```

Edit the TODO list.  There are several ways to do this, but let's say we just move `B` to the end, ready to receive fixes.  So literally just move the line for `B` to the end of the list.  Now you have

```
A -- C' -- D' -- B' <--(master)
```

(where `x'` is a rewrite of `x` that does the same thing but on a different "base" - i.e. different parent).

Of course you really want `master^` (omitting `B'` for now).  Better test it (it's a new code state).  Then you'll have to force-push

```
git push -f master^:master
```

There are other ways as well, but these cover the major options.